# undefined $load property when loading view in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I need to do the process of loading a view inside my controller which can be done using something like:

```
$main['menu'] = $this->load->view('myView', NULL, TRUE);
```

but when executing I receive an error saying 
    Undefined property: MainController::$load

How can this be fixed, or if you can give me another way to do the work

Comment: Where did you get the idea of using $load property of a controller?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo i need to load a view into another view and pass the loaded content to a new one, see here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221371/best-method-of-including-views-within-views-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate view in your controller with:

```
// get the view object
$view = View::make('myView'));

// get view content as string
$content = $view->render();

// pass the content to another view
$anotherView = View::make('anotherView', array('content' => $content));
```

You can read more about how to use views in Laravel 4 here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#views. I suggest you have a look here as it seems that what you're trying to do is not the standard way of doing stuff in Laravel.