# how to create function for load menu in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i'm litte confuse about this, so i wanna make one function which called **menu_function**.

for what? so all file php in view, will load this **menu_function**

this **menu_function** will load menu option in each php file in view, so it will load different menu option in different php file in view

what i'm think is like this

```
public function menu_function()
{
    $dataV["menu"] = "<a href='profit' style='color:blue; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;'>Profit PT</a>";
    $dataV["menu1"] = "<a href='profit/member' style='color:blue; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;'>Profit Member</a>";
    $this->load->view("test", $dataV);
}
```

i think is bad having html tag in controller or i already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221371/best-method-of-including-views-within-views-in-codeigniter), according that is efficient i make another php in view just for menu option and load in another view?

why i want to make this? so in future if i wanna add another menu option or remove 1 or more menu option just change in 1 file, not having open all view and remove menu option 1 by 1.

maybe another suggest? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is to create a templates folder inside the views directory, and put there view files that you may require from several controllers.
/application/views/templates

Let's name that file *header.php* and it would look like this

```
<a href='<?php echo site_url('profit'); ?>' style='color:blue; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;'>Profit PT</a>
<a href='<?php echo site_url('profit/member); ?>' style='color:blue; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;'>Profit Member</a>
```

Then, you could include this template in every controller you would want

```
$this->load->view('templates/header');
```

Also, for future reference, if you want a function to be available in different controllers you can:

1. [Extend the CI_Controller core class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html).

   `class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
       public function __construct() {
           parent::__construct();
       }
       /* define here all the functions you want */
   }`

   Then you would create your controllers extending MY_Controller instead of CI_Controller whenever you would want to call the functions.
2. Use [helpers](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html), [libraries](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) and [drivers](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_drivers.html).

Comment: thanks, so it like link i give, but how to use it in different way. thanks i figure it now