# How to include header in ci?

Tags: codeigniter

controller: Test.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Test extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        parent :: __construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('index');
    }
}
```

view : index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <?php include('header.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new in codeigniter and I want to include header.php file in index.php and I am using include function in view but I think that is not the correct way to include header file inside the index.php then what is the correct way please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best method of including views within views in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221371/best-method-of-including-views-within-views-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Codeigniter doc's pretty good now https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can include like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php  $this->load->view('header'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller like this

```
 public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('index');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called partial views of Codeigniter on the rule of codeigniter you will include any page or header top or bottom of the website you will used controller

```
class Your_controller extend CI_controller{
 public function index(){
 $this->load->view('header');
 $this->load->view('index');
 }  
}
```