# Can't load header & footer file on codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I had write the header and footer file on CI. But idk why it doesn't load to the home.php file.

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); 
class Home extends CI_Controller {
public function home($page = 'home') {
    if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')) {
        show_404();
    }
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$page);      
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: does templates folder exists in views??

Comment: Is it showing any error?

Comment: [best methods to include nested views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221371/best-method-of-including-views-within-views-in-codeigniter) Refer this, it may help you